# How do I authenticate HTTP requests in WordPress 4.7?

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, rest

The new WordPress v4.7 integrates [WordPress REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) plugin into the core of WP. This makes posts, pages, and media publicly available using HTTP calls even on private sites.

Is there a setting in WP to block or authenticate GET and POST (etc.) requests?

I'm building an Angular 1.5 REST app with WP and it would be great to authenticate these public requests.

Comment: The members plugin by Justin Tadlock https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/ now has an option to require authentication to the REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest WordPress API now includes [authentication for all requests](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/frequently-asked-questions/#require-authentication-for-all-requests). Adding the filter `is_user_logged_in` to the [rest_authentication_errors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_authentication_errors/) filer should require authentication:

```php
add_filter(&#039;rest_authentication_errors&#039;, function($result) {
    if (!empty($result)) {
        return $result;
    }
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        return new WP_Error(&#039;rest_not_logged_in&#039;, &#039;You are not currently logged in.&#039;, array(&#039;status&#039; => 401));
    }
    return $result;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can authenticate the requests. I found a link inside the documentation about authentication. It works with Cookies, OAuth and Password as well.

[WordPress API Authentication](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/)

Comment: I've come across this page but maybe I missed something? In my testing I used postman to test GET `.../wp-json/wp/v2/posts` and the request went through without verifying any credentials. I haven't been able to find any WP setting to disable this (at the minimum) now that this behavior is included by default.